# Android - Jetpack - Make lazily created class lifecycle aware

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-lifecycle

Got an interesting case to solve.

#### Backstory

I have a `ViewModel` that is a `LifecycleObserver`, I'm following a nice architectural pattern where this VM is serving the overall screen logic, and is composing smaller VMs inside to serve components that are on screen.

In order to make these smaller VMs work out of the box, I make them lifecycle aware on the `onCreate` of the container ViewModel.

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
    super.onCreate(owner)
    smallerVMs.forEach(owner.lifecycle::addObserver)
}
```

#### Problem

However, I have `n` other small VMs that I will instantiate on demand, depending on an API call.

Because I don't have reference of them until they're instantiated, I can't make them lifecycle aware on `onCreate` as mentioned above.

And when the API is back with results, and I do instantiate them, I don't have a hold of the `LifecycleOwner` instance!

I thought of caching the `LifecyclerOwner` in `onCreate`, but that means keeping reference to the View in a VM, which is not a good practice in MVVM.

Any thoughts on this?
Thanks in advance!

*Disclaimer: Having the smaller VMs inside the big VM is essential, as the smaller VMs are reusable presentation pieces across the whole app*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having every single child object observe the same life cycle owner, you should delegate since you're employing [Composite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) pattern:

Assuming you're using [LifecycleEventObserver](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/LifecycleEventObserver) (since [LifeCycleObserver](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/LifecycleObserver) should not be used directly):

```
override fun onStateChanged(LifecycleOwner source, Lifecycle.Event event) {
    smallerVMS.forEach { it.onStateChanged(source, event) }
}
```

Then it doesn't matter *when* the child VMs are created - as long as they're in that list they'll get every callback when the parent does, as if they were observing themselves.

Comment: Thank you, I like the approach, didn't know the callback existed!
However, that doesn't notify the newly created controllers of an `onCreate` callback, I will need to invoke that manually it seems, right?

Comment: Yes. But hopefully you don't need any dependency on the lifecycle owner, just the knowledge that it is created? Which is implied if you are in a position to be running code and creating new child VMs.

Comment: That is correct, I will need to adapt the small VMs to that timing indeed.
That was helpful, thank you!